# No version set for command java - asdf

Tags: java, bash, asdf-vm

I'm now using [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) on my Lubuntu machine in a bash environment and it gives me the message:

```
stephane@stephane-pc:~/dev$ cd
No version set for command java
Consider adding one of the following versions in your config file at 
java adoptopenjdk-15.0.2+7
```

I have only one asdf project which is located in the `~/work/example/dev/ExampleBooster` directory:

```
12:07 $ cat .tool-versions 
java adoptopenjdk-15.0.2+7
nodejs 12.13.1
tflint 0.28.1
terraform-validator 3.1.3
packer 1.7.2
terraform 0.15.3
adr-tools 3.0.0
pre-commit 1.21.0
maven 3.8.4
```

My `asdf` configuration `~/dev/commands/asdf.config.sh` file contains:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

source $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh
source $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash
# Setting the JAVA_HOME variable
. ~/.asdf/plugins/java/set-java-home.bash

# If asdf provides the maven plugin then use the plugin instead of the system maven if any
if asdf current maven > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  export MAVEN_HOME=$(asdf where maven)
  export PATH=$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin
fi
```

UPDATE: I added the line `java adoptopenjdk-15.0.2+7` in the `~/.tool-versions` file and that solved the issue.

Comment: Which java plugin are you using?

Comment: I did this: `asdf plugin-add java` and `asdf install java adoptopenjdk-15.0.2+7`

Answer (score 4):

I tried locally and it worked as expected.

#### Steps

Install required tools:

```
apt-get update -y && apt-get -y  install curl git dirmngr gpg gawk && git clone https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf.git ~/.asdf --branch v0.8.1 && . $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh
```

Add java plugin

```
asdf plugin add java https://github.com/halcyon/asdf-java.git
```

Install it

```
asdf install java adoptopenjdk-15.0.2+7
```

Config it

```
asdf global java adoptopenjdk-15.0.2+7
```

After the previous steps, java is ready to use and it appears in the `$HOME/.tool-versions`

[image: java with asdf]

I didn't need any other configuration to get Java on the system.

#### Docker

Just to try or determinate that your system could be misconfigured, you could use docker to have a fresh and temporary ubuntu. In this environment you could try **asdf** from the scratch:

```
docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

#### Sources

- https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html#_6-set-a-version
- https://github.com/halcyon/asdf-java

Comment: The issue never shows up in the projects in which I installed the Java plugin and Java language. It shows up only when entering a directory in which I did not install a Java language.

Comment: Faced with the same error message I solved it by running the command `asdf global yarn 1.22.5`